# Bootstrap 4 - change text color of dropdown-toggle when the dropdown is opened

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to change the color of opened dropdown-toggle. As you can see on the pic below, the "Služby" dropdown-toggle text color stays white when I click on it and open the dropdown, while I want it to be beige. I tried different css pseudo-classes like active, focus etc. but nothing worked.

[image: Dropdown]

Here is the code:

```html
<!--Collapsing sidebar-->
<div class="collapse" id="sidebar">
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">O nás <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Portfolio<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-2 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="utilitiesDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Služby
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu-sidebar" aria-labelledby="utilitiesDropdown">
                    <h6 class="dropdown-item my-1" href="#">Link 1</h6>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-2 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="utilitiesDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Ceník
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="utilitiesDropdown">
                    <h6 class="dropdown-item" href="#">Content &amp; Components</h6>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-2"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Objednávka<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item my-2"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Kontakt<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to have the dropdown-toggle change text color when the dropdown is opened? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the nav-link if you want to change that text... For example

```
<a class="nav-link text-primary..."
```

Or add a style

```
.nav-link{
 color:#000 -- The color you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below css

```
 .navbar-nav .show a {
     color: brown !important; /* color you want to show */
 }
```